# concurrent Threads Merge Sort

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mergesort

I have to code a concurrent Merge Sort Aplication. Every time the array gets split up, I have to create a new thread for the right half (max. Number of Threads is 5 -> so 5 Times) which continues the Mergesort algorithm.

[image]

That's my program:

```
class Mergesorts implements Runnable{

    private int[] internal;

    Mergesorts(int[] arr) {
        internal = arr;
    }

    private void processCommand(int [] array) {
        if (array.length > 1) { 
            int[] left = leftHalf(array);
            int[] right = rightHalf(array);
            processCommand(left);
            processCommand(right);
            merge(array, left, right);
        }
    }

    public int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int size2 = array.length - size1;
        int[] right = new int[size2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            right[i] = array[i + size1];
        }
        return right;
    }

    public void run() {
        processCommand(internal);
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite my code to sort concurrently as described above?

How can i edit my code so it only creates up to 5 Threads and not more?

```
private void processCommand(int [] array) {
    if (array.length > 1) {


        int[] right = rightHalf(array);
        int[] left = leftHalf(array);


        Mergesorts worker2 = new Mergesorts(right);
        Thread s = new Thread(worker2);
        s.start();

        processCommand(left);

        try {
            s.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        merge(array, left, right);}

}
```

Comment: And what is the question? And who on earth is upvoting a question .... that isnt a question?!

Comment: The question is where in my code should i create the new Threads which continues doing the same algorithm

Comment: I wish that SO required you to do some sort of test before you get to post. That way we wouldn't have these half-assed questions. It takes unnecessary time to coax the asker to formulate the question into an answerable form.

Comment: @Merve You need to create a new thread every time you divide the array into two. The first half can continue to process the first half, and the new thread gets to process the second half.

Comment: Please provide enough demo or idea for getting solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the new thread in the processCommand() method, not in the rightHalf() method.  If you have threads available, then instead of the line calling processCommand(right), construct a new Mergesorts object on `right` and start a thread with it.  Don't forget to call join() on the thread to ensure it completes before doing the merge.

To improve parallelism, you can start the new thread on the right half of the array before processing the left half of the array, so both are done at the same time - that is, move processCommand(left) to after the block that either does processCommand(right) or starts a new thread.  The join() call should be after both halves are done, but before the merge.

Edit:  you are getting closer; to address your comment, you need something like this:

```
private void processCommand(int [] array) {
    if (array.length <= 1)
        {return;}

    int[] left = leftHalf(array);
    int[] right = rightHalf(array);
    Thread rightThread = null;

    if (b <= 5) {
        ++b;
        Mergesorts worker = new Mergesorts(right);
        rightThread = new Thread(worker);
        rightThread.start();
    } else {
        processCommand(right);
    }

    processCommand(left);

    if (null != rightThread) {
        try {
            rightThread.join();
            b--
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // better error handling would be good
        }
    }

    merge(array, left, right);
}
```

`b` also needs to be volatile to ensure the different threads can see how many threads are currently executing.

Comment: i can't put the join() call after both halves, because then s cannot be resolved and btw. why does my code create more then 5 Threads? Can you please help me!

Comment: You are getting closer.  Added some code to my answer to clarify.

Comment: i wrote right after the  class Mergesorts implements Runnable{ private volatile int b=0;  but its stil creating more then 5 threads :(